# How I can remove this nested for loops, it take too much time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nested, logic

```
for i,row_1 in df_1.iterrows():
   for j, row_2 in df_2.iterrows():
      if row_1['RECKEY'] == row_2['RECKEY']:
         df_1.loc[i ,'RECKEY'] = df_2.loc[j ,'RECKEY_NEW']
```

How do I build a filter which does this?

I tried the following without any success.

```
df_1.loc[df_1.RECKEY.isin(df_2.RECKEY), 'RECKEY'] = df_2.loc['RECKEY_NEW']
```

Output:

```
Index: [])
'RECKEY_NEW'
```

Comment: It is generally bad practice to loop through a pandas dataframe, as it is slow.  Could you provide an example of your dataframe, and expected output?

Answer (score 2):

Produce basic structure of your dataframe it helps in solving the problem better. this !works!

```
df_1.loc[df_1["RECKEY"]==df_2["RECKEY"],'RECKEY']=df_2["RECKEY"]
```

Comment: it defnitely works i checked on my data, only condition is number of rows must be same in df1 and df2

Comment: yes you are right it works when df1 and df2 are same in length

Answer (score 1):

You should use merge, that will solve your problem.

```
new_df = df_1.merge(df_2[['RECKEY_NEW','RECKEY']], left_on='RECKEY', 
right_on='RECKEY')
new_df['RECKEY'] = new_df['RECKEY_NEW'].astype(int)
```

Comment: This will merge both data frames on the basis of 'RECKEY' and add 'RECKEY_NEW' column to dataframe df_1

Comment: This solution will work in both cases, when the dataframes have the same number of rows and when they haven't